# SQL query, check if cells with the same value in column A have the same value in column B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a lot of columns and rows such as the below example :

[image: Example table for query]

I'm trying to find Orders that are partially complete, such that there is at least one `Item Line` record for the order that does have a `Goods Issue Date` value **and** one `Item Line` record for the order that does *not* have a `Goods Issue Date` value. I can easily get orders with no goods issue date at all, but I need to know the orders that have some item lines with a date and some without.

Looking at the sample data above, I should only see results for Order #1, because Orders 2,3, and 5 are all fully complete and Order 4 has not started yet.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Would it be possible for you to post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Posting images in place of code or sample data is considered rude here. It makes it harder for us to help you, because we have to re-type your samples to try it ourselves, and leads to downvotes.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what results you are expecting. Do you want all of the Order #1 records and columns, do you want just one record back with Order #1? Maybe just the incomplete lines in the order?

Comment: Hello and thank you for welcoming me! I am sorry if I made a few noob errors such as putting an image however I tried to put in a table via a website I found from the forums here (I think it was sense something) but the preview of my message was always wrong and so I decided to put in an image

Comment: I have gotten a good response from the below suggestions. but just to make it clear, I wanted to get all columns but only the row with order 1. I asked this question for only the orders that haven't got completely a goods issue date. Then I will use the same technique to get all orders that have been completely Goods issued (so all item lines) and finally orders that have no goods issue date whatsoever. I thought if I can get one example I can figure out the others :) Sorry if the formulation of my question was a bit iffy, I am not english. I appreciate all the support really!! Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    theTable t1
WHERE
    t1.`Goods Issue Date` IS NULL
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT
                    *
                 FROM
                    theTable t2
                 WHERE
                    t2.`Order` = t1.`Order`
                    AND t2.`Goods Issue Date` IS NOT NULL );
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e37801/2)

You can also use a simple `IN` if `Order` is non-nullable

```
SELECT  *
FROM    theTable
WHERE   `Goods Issue Date` IS NULL
        AND `Order` IN (
           SELECT  `Order` 
           FROM    theTable 
           WHERE   `Goods Issue Date` IS NOT NULL 
        )
```

Comment: Oh woaw Thank you very much JamieD77! I will read a little bit about the "EXISTS" and combining two SELECTS like you did! Thank you for this quick response, it helps me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to identify the bad orders. Here I've done this with a CTE (common table expression) for readability but it can be accomplished with a simple subquery in the join statement.

Once you have that, simply join the results back on the parent table.

```
WITH BadOrders AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   table
    WHERE [Goods Issue Date] IS NULL)
SELECT table.*
FROM   table
       JOIN BadOrders ON table.Order = BadOrders.Order
```